# flutter upgrade, and pub upgrade on android studio, Error "Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter <command> -h') for available flutter commands and options."

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-upgrade, flutter-run

i updated my flutter/ dart version on android studio after then i upgraded my dependencies using pub upgrade, then i ran flutter clean the flutter pub get. when i run my app i get an error
"Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter  -h') for available flutter commands and options."
i seem not to find the answer any where o stackoverflow. and no documentation talking about it.

the first thing i did was to shot down my emulator and shot down android studio. thinking its an update i have to restart the android studio but it didnt go so i shot down my computer and no solution.
Again i ran flutter doctor and had this response
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.2416], locale en-US)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
X cmdline-tools component is missing
Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
X Android license status unknown.
Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[X] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps
X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary to develop Windows apps.
Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.81.1)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] Network resources

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
i tried searces around the web and its all about using flutter commands.